# How to use an external SVG for CSS filter:url()?

Tags: css, svg, reference, svg-filters

I have a HTML document. I'm able to add to the CSS, but not the HTML itself.

I'm trying to apply a SVG filter to images using the `filter:url()` property. As I can't touch the HTML, I can't add `<svg><defs><filter></filter></defs></svg>`. Instead, I'm trying to reference it externally, which is apparently possible.

My SVG is located at http://puu.sh/m1UcD/bba51a3b3d.svg, and it contains the following text:
`<filter id="colorMatrix">
  <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="1 0 0 -0.2 -0.1, 0 5 0 0 -0.1, 0 0 1 -0.2 -0.1, 0 0 0 1 0"/>
</filter>`

I've attempted to use
`filter:url(http://puu.sh/m1UcD/bba51a3b3d.svg#colorMatrix);
-webkit-filter:url(http://puu.sh/m1UcD/bba51a3b3d.svg#colorMatrix);`
as the CSS property but the effect doesn't render.

Comment: External references work in FF, but they don't work in Chrome.

Comment: Also, this kind of reference should be made inside an svg document, not inside a text element with a `.svg` extension.